# 2 Questions, 1: LDD V4.3.12 not connecting to internet 2: I can't find any EV3 electric parts

Tags: ev3, software, ldd

(I'm new to LDD)

Hi, I'm trying to use LDD for designing a robot for my Lego Robotics Class. It's just whenever I launch LDD, it just keeps saying that I'm not connected to internet and asking if I want to launch offline mode. (This may be fixed when the internet is fixed) I also can't find any EV3 parts in the menu's for that sort of stuff. I've tried the filter thing and it did nothing, so I don't really know what to do for either problem.

Any help?